# if statement not reading characters in string

Tags: python

I am working on a program to determine if a license plate is in the correct order using python 3.4 (I am beginning programming, and doing some self assigned home work).

The license plate should be in the order of three letters, and three numbers for correct order.

This is my code:

```
#Get data from user
plate = input('Enter the lisence plate number: ')

#Determine if style is old or new
if len(plate) == 6 and plate[0] >= "A" and plate[0] <= "Z"\
   and plate[1] >= "A" and plate[1] <= "Z"\
   and plate[2] >= "A" and plate[2] <= "Z"\
   and plate[3] >= "0" and plate[1] <= "9"\
   and plate[4] >= "0" and plate[4] <= "9"\
   and plate[5] >= "0" and plate[5] <= "9":
    verd = 'works'
else: 
    verd = 'Not work'

#print results
    print(verd)
```

When I enter the license plate ABC123, it is telling me that it doesn't work.

I have been trying everything, and can not figure out why this isn't working.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `correct order using python 3.4`

Comment: Aside from the regexp suggestion, you could also write that as: `if len(plate) == 6 and plate[:3].isupper() and plate[3:].isdigit():`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the way, the error in your method is in the third condition -

```
and plate[3] >= "0" and plate[1] <= "9"   <-------- Notice that you are using `plate[1]` instead of [3]
```

Change it to -

```
and plate[3] >= "0" and plate[3] <= "9"
```

Comment: By the way , when these kinds of condition go wrong, I usually print each condition separately , to find out which one is actually failing. Sometimes you can even find out the wrong one , just by trying to separate them.

Answer (score 1):

A simple regex will do this job.

```
re.match(r'[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{3}$', s)
```

Since `re.match` tries to match from the begining of the string, you don't need to use start of the line anchor `^`.

**Example:**

```
>>> import re
>>> def check(s):
    if re.match(r'[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{3}$', s):
        print('works')
    else:
        print('Not work')


>>> check(input('Enter the lisence plate number: '))
Enter the lisence plate number: ABC123
works
>>> check(input('Enter the lisence plate number: '))
Enter the lisence plate number: ABCDEF
Not work
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  I am not quite at that level yet....  I am using a work book, and am under the if statement section (brand new to coding).  My solution matches the solution they give.  Any idea on why this code isn't working?

Comment: Thanks for the education!

Comment: OMG, why 2 downvotes? Don't know what's wrong with alternate answer? @Downvoter whar if the length of the string is about 120 chars. No one willing to check for each char separately according to the position. Posted this comment not to get upvotes, but to know why..

Comment: No idea, I like the regex, +1 from me.

Comment: "whar if the length of the string is about 120 chars" --- it does not work like that. For this very task the string is of the fixed size and the OP is a beginner that needed help in *understanding* why their code is broken. Unless you're willing to write code for them forever - this answer does not address the OP's problem.

Comment: ya, this won't address the problem, but I'm suggesting him to don't do like you did, In future you should consider regex for these cases.

Comment: ya, I know you people hate regex,,

Answer (score 0):

on line :

```
and plate[3] >= "0" and plate[1] <= "9"\
```

change '1' to '3' like this:

```
and plate[3] >= "0" and plate[3] <= "9"\
```

Comment: well, it took me 10 minutes to figure this out... by the time i answered, someone else answered.

Answer (score 0):

Your bug is a typo.

```
   and plate[3] >= "0" and plate[1] <= "9"\
```

versus

```
   and plate[3] >= "0" and plate[3] <= "9"\
```

Also, the indentation of `print(verd)` is off; it's in the `else` block, so it would only print anything if the license wasn't valid.

Here's your code with minimal changes to get it working:

```
#Get data from user
plate = input('Enter the lisence plate number: ')

#Determine if style is old or new
if len(plate) == 6 and plate[0] >= "A" and plate[0] <= "Z"\
   and plate[1] >= "A" and plate[1] <= "Z"\
   and plate[2] >= "A" and plate[2] <= "Z"\
   and plate[3] >= "0" and plate[3] <= "9"\  # Fixed bug here
   and plate[4] >= "0" and plate[4] <= "9"\
   and plate[5] >= "0" and plate[5] <= "9":
    verd = 'works'
else:
    verd = 'Not work'

#print results
print(verd)  # Fixed bug here
```

However, your code has a few other issues, so here's an improved version:

```
# Get data from user
plate = input('Enter the license plate number: ')

# Determine if style is old or new
if (len(plate) == 6 and
    'A' <= plate[0] <= 'Z' and
    'A' <= plate[1] <= 'Z' and
    'A' <= plate[2] <= 'Z' and
    '0' <= plate[3] <= '9' and
    '0' <= plate[4] <= '9' and
    '0' <= plate[5] <= '9'):
    verd = 'Valid'
else:
    verd = 'Invalid'

print(verd)
```

You could also do this:

```
# Get data from user
plate = input('Enter the license plate number: ')

# Determine if style is old or new
if (len(plate) == 6 and
    plate[:3].isupper() and plate[:3].isalpha() and
    plate[3:].isdigit():
    verd = 'Valid'
else:
    verd = 'Invalid'

print(verd)
```

But generally, I would say the best/cleanest way is the regular expression method:

```
import re

plate = input('Enter the license plate number: ')

if re.match(r'^[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{3}$', plate):
    print('Valid')
else:
    print('Invalid')
```

Comment: Thanks man, very helpful, I didn't think you could do some of that sentax